# Include Procfile and .ebextension folder in Jenkins ZIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, procfile, ebextensions

I have a Maven Project with this folder structure (after run 'maven clean install' through jenkins):

[image]

PS: there are other files and directories inside this 'target' folder, but the ones I need are just those.

Well, for AWS deployment, I need to create a ZIP file with this exact structure (missing the 'ebs' folder):

[image]

My pipeline, in Jenkins, creates the ZIP with the jar ane 'ebs' folder inside, but I need Procfile and .ebextensions at root level, outside 'ebs' folder.

Jenkins configuration:

[image]

I also tried "ebs", "ebs/", "ebs/*" and "ebs/.". None works. What am I doing wrong? Should be simple to include files in ZIP package, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

To include Procfile file and .ebextensions folder inside ZIP package generated by Jenkins, the first step is to eliminate the 'ebs' folder during maven build.

With every file/directory inside target root, jenkins 'includes' configuration is: `myapp.jar,Procfile,.ebextensions/**/*`